# Problema com logica em java

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou com um problema e acredito que seja de logica mesmo, porém não consigo encontrar. Tenho 4 listas e tenho que agrupar os mercados de de uma região, depois tenho uma lista com todos os produtos vinculados ao mercado e tenho a Minha lista que são as listas dos produtos escolhidos. Quero o nome do mercado e o soma dos valores de se fosse realizar uma compra nele mas nenhum mercado pode ser comparado se não tiver todos os produtos.

```
 Listas l=Listas.getInstance();
    int i =1;  //Regiaoo.getIdReg();
    List<prodmerc> tempPM = new ArrayList();
    List<prodmerc> tempPM1 = new ArrayList();
    List<FiltraMercados> fm=new ArrayList();


    FiltraMercados ff=new FiltraMercados();
    for (int ii=0;ii<l.getM().size();ii++){
        for (int j=0;j<l.getMl().size();j++){
            for (int jj=0;jj<l.getPm().size();jj++){
                if(l.getPm().get(jj).getMercID()==l.getM().get(ii).getMercID() && l.getPm().get(jj).getProdID()==l.getMl().get(j).getP().getProdID() && l.getM().get(ii).getRegID()==i){
                    FiltraMercados f=new FiltraMercados(l.getM().get(ii),l.getMl().get(j).getP().getProdID(),(l.getPm().get(jj).getPmPreco()*l.getMl().get(j).getQtda()));
                    fm.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, seu código está bem complicado de se entender. Eu vejo diversos problemas, mas como não é possível sair querendo corrigir tudo de uma vez, primeiro eu aconselho que renomeie as variáveis para nomes mais intuitivos. Não dá para saber o que é cada variável ai. Depois disso, podemos ver se fica mais fácil de entender o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
Amigo eu para esse tipo de problema primeiramente eu organizo o pensamento, logo a logica ficara organizada.
1º - Validações de exclusão - Facilita que nao vamos comparar tudo
2º - Regras

Tem mais coisas porem com isso tu já consegue melhorar teu código
Primeiro você fez um bubble sort que pode com certeza ser melhorado (meu ponto de vista).

Vamos la
1º - Exclusão, pegue somente a região que você quer com um método depois veja somente aqueles que possuem os produtos que você necessita, recomendo utiliza hash que fica bem melhor e nao precisa varrer a lista de produtos.
Repare bem que neste método não sera feito nenhum laço (for ou while), no máximo um laço para preencher a lista de estado e produtos, porem acho que você já deva ter feito isso anteriormente a esta etapa.

2º - Soma dos valores, aconselho a colocar em uma lista hash onde o hash seja o mercado, sendo assim você o coloca o somatório como value e ai apresente na sua aplicação

Acho que se você seguir esses passos vai conseguir o que quer.
Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer duvida posta ai que tento ajudar.